# Can we get estimated plan of a statement in SQL Server as a select query result set OR automate SSMS - display estimated plan command via .NET

Tags: .net, t-sql, smo, sql-server-2008

Using SSMS for the following statement I can see the estimated plan using `Display Estimated Plan` command.

```
select * from adventtureworks.table1;
```

However if I need to get the estimated plan as a result set of select statement, what sql statements do I have to execute?

I need the result in xml format so that I can display in a .net app/ else is there a way to automate the SSMS `Display Estimated Plan` command via .NET?

Comment: It's stat**E**ment (`statment` is wrong - `statement` is correct)

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the [estimated execution plan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187757.aspx) with:

```
SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON
```

Note that with this option turned on, SQL is no longer executed.  The plan to execute it is generated and returned.